# Problem with refreshing the access token

Tags: 9, authentication-authorization

I am building an app which uses Drupal (9.4.8) as the API. I am using the Simple OAuth module to authorise the client. I have got almost everything working fine, I am receiving the Access Token and the Refresh Token as expected. But, after a lot of searching, I still can't find out which path I need to refresh the tokens.

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-wUKkQa1OM) tokens can be refreshed on the path "/simple-oauth/refresh". But that path doesn't exist and I guess the video refers to an old version of the module...

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: What is the precise version of the module you are using and can you confirm the module is this one? https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth

Comment: Yes, that's the module, version 5.2.0

Comment: Ok, I have made some progress. Got it to working on Talend API Tester. By following these instructions here: [link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#page-47). The refresh url should be /oauth/token (same as login). You also need to send the grant_type and client_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it working with the following steps:

In the Auth strategy in nuxt.config.js

- Set the refresh path to **/oauth/token**
  (I also added a query string, ?refresh to distinguish out from the login path)
- Add this to the header **'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'**

Here's the code:

```
    refresh: {
     url: '/oauth/token?refresh',
     method: 'post',
     headers: { 'Accept': '*/*','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    },
```

I still had problems sending the body in the x-www-form-urlencoded format, so I then created an Axios interceptor plugin to alter the request.
This plugin (~/plugins/axios.js) intercepts request made to /oauth/token?refresh and puts the **grant type**, the **refresh token** and the **client id** in the correct format.

Here's the plugin:

```
var qs = require('qs');

export default function ({ $axios, redirect }) {
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    if (config.url == '/oauth/token?refresh') {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(config.data);
      const refreshToken params.get('refresh_token');
      config.data = qs.stringify({'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': refreshToken,'client_id':'xxxxx-your-client-id-XXXX'})
    }
  })
}
```